# Find files older than X days with name

Tags: bash

I’m trying to use the find command in bash. Finding the file by matching part of the name of a file and the age of the file like so:

```
find . -name “*sample*” -type f -print -mtime +5
```

Which will print all the files in the current directory containing the name sample. What I want is however is to only print those older than 5 days and it doesn’t matter what number I set the -mtime parameter to it always prints out all the files containing sample regardless.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`find` expects arguments grouped together - `Tests` (`name`, `mtime`, `type` etc) must come before `Action` (`print`, `exec` etc).

The following should work:

```
find . -name “*sample*” -type f -mtime +5 -print
```

Comment: *"Must"* isn't entirely correct; the predicates are processed in order, and the first which fails will abort further procesing of that particular file. Using `-print -false` is correct and idiomatic, though you rarely need that in practice.